# Image over cell breaks after conversion to HTML

Tags: excel, excel-interop, vba

I am adding image over select cell, image is added perfectly over cells but when i convert that sheet to html the image breaks 
Here is the code i am using to add image over cells

```
Public Function SetImage(tag As String)
'tag is the selected image path
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

      Dim shp, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(tag)

    With shp
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Left = rng.Left
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Width = .Width / Application.Max(.Width / rng.Width, _
                                          .Height / rng.Height)
                                          Visible = True
    End With
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ShowErrorInfo ("SetTag")
End Function
```

Here is the result of this function

[image]

but after conversion image shows in webpage as

[image]

Excel converts the image like this.
I am using mocrosft interope libraries to convert excel sheet to webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
Adding picture as shape has solved the problem

```
Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=tag, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height
```